# How do I address an envelope to a married couple, who are respectively Professor and Dr?

Tags: names

The form Mr & Mrs (or Ms) gives way to Dr & Mrs, or Professor & Mrs, or The Rev'd and Mrs, where the lady is a traditionalist who does not have a profession of her own.

But when the lady has a professional title and the husband doesn't, what do you write? Is it Mr & Dr, or Dr & Mr?

I actually do know a couple to whom I send a Christmas card where the gentleman is a Professor (emeritus) and the lady is a senior lecturer and usually addressed Dr. Do I write Professor & Dr Stone?

Since I am operating entirely within Britain, an authoritative British answer would be preferred. I can well imagine that American practice might be quite different.

Comment: I imagine it's official title (Princess), then degree (Reverend), then rank (Professor), then gendered term (Mrs), so you'd address it as Dr and Professor or Dr and Mr, as a degree outweighs a rank and should be listed first. If they share a surname, you might avoid it altogether by using The Stones, The Stone Family, or House Stone. I have no reference for this guess, alas.

Comment: I think you need to consult a book of etiquette for this one.

Comment: I'd suggest skirting this issue entirely by avoiding any use of titles and using their first names instead: *Barry and Judith Stone* (or *Judith and Barry Stone*, if you're feeling ***really*** brave).

Comment: Professor Barry and Dr Judith Stone / Mr Barry and Dr Judith Stone

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks Edwin. Oh dear, I got it wrong. I wrote Professor and Dr D. Stone (D. being the husband's initial). should have asked you first! So in future it is Professor Donald and Dr Elizabeth Stone?

Comment: When you really get to know them, 'Don & Liz'. Seriously, the 'Mrs David Cameron' requirement has been relaxed. 'Traditionally, it is considered incorrect for a married woman or a widow to be addressed by her own forename or initials, as this implies that her marriage has been dissolved. However, it is becoming increasingly customary for married women and widows to use their own forenames and initials.' {[Debretts](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/titles/untitled-women-0)!}

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This particular couple are definitely NOT Don & Liz, nor ever likely to be! When I was at school in the 1950s the rule I was given was that in the case of widows, or where the couple were living separately, the lady's own name/initials should be used. And that is the rule to which I have adhered all my life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In British custom, one would write on the envelope

> Prof J R Ewing and Dr E M Ewing

Note that the surname is repeated, because the wife is **notable in her own right** and not merely as "Mrs J R Ewing". This is particularly the case if the wife is still using her maiden name:

> Prof J R Ewing and Dr E M Crump

If you wanted to be particularly formal, then post-nominal letters can be added, again separately:

> Prof J R Ewing OM and Dr E M Ewing FRCP
>   Prof J R Ewing OM and Dr E M Crump FRCP

In formal communications, the husband is **always** addressed first, even if he's just a plain Mr. However in this case it may be preferable to use the slightly more formal *Esq*, particularly if the wife has post-nominal letters; again, because the wife is notable in her own right, she's accorded everything going. If you choose to use *Mr* instead of *Esq* then make the wife match:

> J R Ewing Esq and Dr E M Ewing FRCP
>   Mr J R Ewing and Dr E M Ewing
>   Vice Admiral Sir T J H Laurence KCVO CB CSM ADC(P) & HRH Princess Anne, The Princess Royal KG KT GCVO GCStJ QSO GCL

None of this precludes an ordinary "Mr & Mrs J R Ewing", or (if **he** has a qualification and **she** doesn't) "Dr & Mrs J R Ewing". The point is that if the couple has to be dealt with separately because the wife has stuff to be listed in her own right, then they are written separately in order that that can be made clear. It would never be right to write to "Mr & Dr J R Ewing", and even "Mr J R  & Dr E M Ewing" is not strictly correct, although often seen and certainly more acceptable than the former.

[Debrett's on joint forms of address](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/ask-debretts-expert/questions-joint-forms-address)
[Debrett's on post-nominal letters](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/ask-debretts-expert/questions-letters-after-name)

Comment: Those were the same rules I long ago learned here in the States, too.

Comment: Assuming one is not including post-nominal letters (e.g. on something as informal as a Christmas card), does "Professor K. and Dr B. Granger" sound alright for a husband and wife pairing?

Comment: @ws2 Is that not covered in my last sentence?

Answer (score -1):

Professors are only called so in an academic setting,
using it in a non-university context is stilted.
Likewise, Doctor is only used for medical doctors
except in an academic setting.  At Los Alamos National
Labs, my father-in-law is always Dr. Stradling.  At
home, he never is.  I have never heard of anyone using
"Professor" except when talking about his or her life
*as* a professor.  A social invitation, a christmas card,
a thank-you note for something done at church -- these
cry out for Mr. or Ms.  Also, never repeat what does not
need to be repeated.  In an academic setting, by all
means, Dr. Barry and Professor Judith Stone, absolutely.